# meaning of comparison

Tags: comparisons

> (1) “You are mistaken in supposing me a beggar. I am **no** beggar;
>   **any more than** yourself or your young ladies.”(Jane Eyre)
>
> (2) “No blame attached to me: I am **as** free from culpability **as**
>   any one of you three.” (Jane Eyre)

In (2), I and the others are compared equivalently, whereas (1) denotes that the word, beggar, could be applied to me less than you all, I guess, and it should be heard somewhat aggressively in this case. Is this right?

Comment: 'No more than' does *not* mean 'less than'; see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/106685/8019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'aggressiveness' here I think belongs to the underlying act of contradiction rather than to the language.

Jane certainly does not say that she is *less a beggar*, merely that she is *not any **more** a beggar* than the others. What you have here is an elliptical construction in which the two negatives *no* and *not* are taken as equivalent, without regard to the fact that the first is realized as a quantifier and the second 'deleted' one would have to be realized as an 'adverb':

> I am **no**        beggar
>   <strike>I am **not**</strike> any more <strike>a beggar</strike> than yourself or &c